# Plot a cone with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm new to plotting graphs in 3D and would like to plot a cone in 3D using matplotlib. It should start with something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874791/disconnected-surfaces-when-plotting-cones) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703275/3d-truncated-cone-in-python)

Comment: I've seen those and I would like something similar to your first comment, but the cone shouldn't be cut off at both edges (ie only have one opening), like this: https://www.iconexperience.com/v_collection/icons/?icon=object_cone

Comment: Did you check the second link? It plots something similar